# python module utils :has no attribute 'centord_histogram'

Tags: python, matplotlib, module

I have problem with importing python module

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


import argparse
import utils
import cv2
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt






image = image.reshape((image.shape[0] * image.shape[1], 3))

# cluster
clt = KMeans(n_clusters = 2)
clt.fit(image)


hist = utils.centord_histogram(clt)
bar = utils.plot_colors(hist, clt.cluster_centers_)



plt.figure()
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(bar)
plt.show()
```

added  import matplotlib as mpl
       mpl.use('TkAgg')
because I'm a Mac user.

when I run the code,

`hist = utils.centord_histogram(clt)`

I get the following:

`AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'centord_histogram'`

error occurred. I have to see the histogram. any advice for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a module from `utils` that you can import by installing utils like `pip install utils`. This is a written code.

Find your answer here:
https://github.com/tarikd/python-kmeans-dominant-colors/blob/master/utils.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write `utils.centroid_histogram` instead of `utils. centord_histogram`?

Answer (score 0):

Use below functions instead of the `utils` module:

```
def centroid_histogram(clt):
        # grab the number of different clusters and create a histogram
        # based on the number of pixels assigned to each cluster
        numLabels = np.arange(0, len(np.unique(clt.labels_)) + 1)
        (hist, _) = np.histogram(clt.labels_, bins = numLabels)
    
        # normalize the histogram, such that it sums to one
        hist = hist.astype("float")
        hist /= hist.sum()
    
        # return the histogram
        return hist
    
    def plot_colors(hist, centroids):
        # initialize the bar chart representing the relative frequency
        # of each of the colors
        bar = np.zeros((50, 300, 3), dtype = "uint8")
        startX = 0
    
        # loop over the percentage of each cluster and the color of
        # each cluster
        for (percent, color) in zip(hist, centroids):
            # plot the relative percentage of each cluster
            endX = startX + (percent * 300)
            cv2.rectangle(bar, (int(startX), 0), (int(endX), 50),
                color.astype("uint8").tolist(), -1)
            startX = endX
        
        # return the bar chart
        return bar
```